# error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ITokenResponse'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular12

I am getting the following error:

> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ITokenResponse'.

I tried to import as suggested in another StackOverflow answer but it gives this error:

> error TS2306: File 'C:/Repository/MAngular/src/app/interfaceModals/ItokenResponse.ts' is not a module.

How should I fix this? The code is as below, I am working with Angular12. Thank you!!

```js
import { Inject, Injectable, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {map, tap} from 'rxjs/operators' ;
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {

  client_id: string = "Manage";
  authKey: string ="auth";
  roleKey: string="role";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId:any) { }

  login(username: string, password: string, userRole: string){
      var data ={
        username: username,
        password: password,
        client_id: this.client_id,
        grant_type: "password",
        role_name: userRole
      };
      this.http.post<ITokenResponse>('url', data)
        .pipe(map( tkDetails => {
          let checkIfTokenConditions =  tkDetails && tkDetails.token;
          //the above statement is lambda expresion. it checks if the 
          if(checkIfTokenConditions){
            this.setAuth(tkDetails);
            this.setRole(tkDetails.role_name);
          }
          return tkDetails;
     }))
      
  }
```

Comment: You miss out import `ItokenResponse` in `AuthenticationService`. Need to add `import { AuthenticationService } from 'file path'` on top.

Comment: i tried that , it gives this error ::
error TS2306: File 'C:/Repository/MAngular/src/app/interfaceModals/ItokenResponse.ts' is not a module.

Comment: Can you share your `ItokenResponse` file? And do you add it into any `Module`'s imports? If yes, please remove it as it is not a module.

Comment: This is my ITokenResponse file . It is in IInterfaceModels
```
interface ITokenResponse{
    token: string,
    expiration: number,
    refresh_token: string,
    role_name: string
}
```
No I have not added to any module

Comment: Add `export` will solve your question. `export interface ITokenResponse { ... }`

Comment: How do I do it?.. Sorry I have very new to Angular.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236769/discussion-between-stilllearning-and-yong-shun).

Answer (score 1):

To share the classes, interfaces, functions, or variables across different files (a.k.a. global scope), you need the [`export`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#exporting-a-declaration) keyword.

> ItokenResponse.ts

```js
export interface ITokenResponse {
    token: string;
    expiration: number;
    refresh_token: string;
    role_name: string;
}
```

Next, you need an [`import`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import) to consume a variable, function, class, interface which is exported from the different module(s).

> authentication-service.ts

```js
import { ITokenResponse } from 'src/app/interfaceModals/ItokenResponse';

export class AuthenticationService {
 ...
}
```